# Identify months with random characters in front

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am looking to identify months which may or may not have one random character in front of them in python. For example I would like to identify:

1. loctober as october
2. yaug as aug

The letters in front are not always l or y, and are in front of more months than just august and october.

I have tried identifying these months like this:

```
odd_months = ['[a-z]jan', '[a-z]january', '[a-z]feb', '[a-z]february', '[a-z]mar', '[a-z]march', 
          '[a-z]apr', '[a-z]april', '[a-z]may', '[a-z]jun', '[a-z]june', '[a-z]jul', 
          '[a-z]july', 'iaug',  '[a-z]august', '[a-z]sep', '[a-z]september', '[a-z]oct', 
          '[a-z]october', '[a-z]nov', '[a-z]november', '[a-z]dec', '[a-z]december']
```

for example

```
'loct' in odd_months #False
```

Comment: '[a-z]jan' is a string not a regex, use `re.compile` to make it regex.

Comment: The `in` operator uses equality (`==`) rather than `re.match`. I'd recommend something similar to @DanilSperansky's approach though. You don't need regular expressions for this.

Comment: I'm assuming it doesn't matter *what* the leading letter is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take advantage of the `calendar` module:

```
import calendar

names_and_abbrs = calendar.month_name[1:] + calendar.month_abbr[1:]

def isOddMonth(name):
    return (name.title() in names_and_abbrs) or (name[1:].title() in names_and_abbrs)
```

Or:

```
def isOddMonth(name):
    return any(n.title() in names_and_abbrs for n in (name, name[1:]))
```

Sample use:

```
isOddMonth('aug') == True
isOddMonth('loct') == True
isOddMonth('DECEMBER') == True
isOddMonth('februa') == False
isOddMonth('') == False
isOddMonth('123') == False
```

Comment: +1 Sets seem to be woefully underused in Python (as far as I can tell). It would improve the performance somewhat, and possibly teach the OP something new.

Answer (score 0):

`'loct' in odd_months` checks whether `odd_months` includes `'loct'` or not. There is no such string in the array, so it returns `False`.

But anyway I think using regexps is overhead. I would suggest completely another approach:

```
def validate(s):
    months = {
        'jan', 'january', 'feb', 'february', 'mar', 'march', 'apr', 'april',
        'may', 'jun', 'june', 'jul', 'july', 'aug', 'august', 'sep', 'september',
        'oct', 'october', 'nov', 'november', 'dec', 'december'
    }

    if s in months:
        return s

    if s[1:] in months:
        return s[1:]

print(validate('apr')) #=> 'apr'
print(validate('qapr')) #=> 'apr'
print(validate('qqapr')) #=> None
```

Comment: Good answer. A set might be marginally faster and perhaps you should also `.lowercase()` the `s`. But it doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: Revenge, possibly. Or maybe someone really likes regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` and a regex to do something along these lines:

```
odd_months={re.compile(r'\w?oct(?:ober)?'): "october", re.compile(r'\w?aug(?:ust)?'): "august"}

for s in ('loct', 'oct', 'loctober', 'yaug', 'waugust', 'nothingburger'):
    for pat, key in odd_months.items():
        if pat.match(s):
            print '"{}"=>{}'.format(s,key)
            break
    else:
        print '"{}" no match'.format(s)
```

Prints:

```
"loct"=>october
"oct"=>october
"loctober"=>october
"yaug"=>august
"waugust"=>august
"nothingburger" no match
```

You can also use the fact that each month is unique and the 3 letter representation is unique. Therefor, you can use a `dict` with both the 3 letter and full name and the `in` operator to test for a month:

```
import calendar
def find_name(x):
   months={k.lower():v for k,v in 
            zip(calendar.month_name[1:]+calendar.month_abbr[1:], calendar.month_name[1:]*2)}    
   for k,v in months.items():
       if k in x.lower():
           return v
   else:
      return False
```

Comment: Thanks. Glad you noticed that the op is actually looking for a conversion, rather than a bool (although the code doesn't reflect that). Lastly, you could use endswith rather than in, although they're both a little too forgiving. But maybe the op doesn't care.